# C++ how to create a simple console application global hotkey

Tags: c++, windows, console-application, global-hotkey

I want to create a console application program that even if not focus, can detect keypress or combination of key press like Ctrl + F1...F10. Then if Ctrl + F1 is press then will do something. I want to create this for personal use only.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Can't be done using standard C++, you have to involve operating-system specific functionality. And you don't tell us what operating system you're targeting. Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Im using windows 7 os. what I tried is the accepted answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006623/registering-a-global-hotkey-without-disabling-its-key) But the program is that I it only register letter "A". and I do not know how to register a combination keypress. And in its while loop I can not detect which key is pressed.

Comment: You can use GetAsyncKeyState

Comment: The linked post is the way to go. It only register the letter A because according to the [list of windows Virtual-Key codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), 0x41 is key code for A. Key code for F1 is `VK_F1` or 0x70. Use a non null modifier if you want to use Ctrl-F1 as explained in [RegisterHotKey MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Registering a Global HotKey without disabling its key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006623/registering-a-global-hotkey-without-disabling-its-key)

Comment: I can add another key for example 'B' by writing this RegisterHotKey(NULL, 1, 0, 0x42); and then I write this ip.ki.wVk = 0x42; I dont know why but I think I should write that. then when run the program dont work like I think it should. So how can I properly add another key? and in its while loop, how can I detect which of the registered key is press? Please answer.