# RegisterHotKey NOREPEAT workaround c++

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to catch inputs and redirect them to another window for certain keys, to do that I `RegisterHotKey` then `UnregisterHotkey` while I `SendInput` then register again. My issue is I need to run only once per keypress and with the re-registering it, `MOD_NOREPEAT` doesn't help as it loops continuously.

How would I go about preventing it from repeating?

My code is structured similarly to the [answer from Fishboy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006623/registering-a-global-hotkey-without-disabling-its-key) which has the same issue:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    RegisterHotKey(NULL, 1, MOD_NOREPEAT, 0x41); //Register A; Third argument should also be "0" instead of "NULL", so it is not seen as pointer argument
    MSG msg = { 0 };
    INPUT ip;
    ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki.wScan = 0;
    ip.ki.time = 0;
    ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
    ip.ki.wVk = 0x41;                            //The key to be pressed is A.
    st
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) != 0) {
        if (msg.message == WM_HOTKEY) {
            UnregisterHotKey(NULL, 1);           //Prevents the loop from caring about the following
            ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;                   //Prepares key down
            SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));    //Key down
            ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;     //Prepares key up
            SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));    //Key up
            cout << "A";                         //Print A if I pressed it
            RegisterHotKey(NULL, 1, 0, 0x41);    //you know...
        }
    }

    UnregisterHotKey(NULL, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot *"redirect"* input using `SendInput`. As you can tell from the function signature alone, there is no place to specify a receiver. Whatever you are trying to accomplish, this is probably not going to pan out the way you hope.

Comment: Before `SendInput` I use `GetForegroundWindow`, `SetForegroundWindow(TargetProgram)` then after sending `SetForegroundWindow(PreviousWindow)` so it does redirect as intended but I didn't include all of that for berevity. My problem is the repeating message for key held, not redirecting `SendInput`.

Comment: [Foreground activation permission is like love: You can’t steal it, it has to be given to you](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090220-00/?p=19083).

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've worked around it by checking `GetKeyState`

```
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));    
cout << "A";                         
RegisterHotKey(NULL, 1, 0, 0x41)
Bool bHeld = true;
while (bHeld == true)
{
    PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, 0x0001);
    if ((GetKeyState(0x41) == 0x0001) || (GetKeyState(0x41) == 0x0000))
    {
                                
        bHeld = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Sleep(20);
    }
}
```

Without `PeekMessage` it was getting stuck in a loop and not resolving.